# Integration of a function of two variables

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, quad

I have a function `func(rp,pi)` for which **I now have the values**. I also **have the values of `rp and pi`**.

I now need to integrate this function within the limits of `0 to pi`

[image]

How do I go about using [quad from scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) to solve this? The doubt I have is, how does quad know that my integral limits are for `pi` and not `rp`?

I tried:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad

integral = []

for a in func:
    result,error = quad(lambda func:a,0,pi)
    integral.append(result)

integral = np.array(integral)
```

Here `func` is the list that has the values of the function. This does give me values, but I am not sure if this is right?

[Here is download link to the file with rp,pi,func](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/480012/W3BV3lnCDljnWtlL/xi_two_dim_0.0_z_1.0_M200%3E1e13_BW_0.0_1-30Mpc_7bins.dat). The first column is `rp`, the second column is `pi` and the third column is `func`

Comment: Since you have a list of values, did you consider discretizing your integral into a sum and using ``np.cumsum()``? I doubt that ``quad()`` will have advantages in this case.

Comment: @Dietrich yes you are true.. Since my values are binned values, as you said it maybe simpler to sum over my bins. Many papers and books that use this function for my particular case mentioned integration, that is why I was wondering about it.. I will try to do a sum and then perform other stuffs that I need and see if it gives me proper results

Comment: @Dietrich but should it be just the `sum` of my function or the `cumulative sum` ?? I am not quite about it

Comment: You're right, it should be ``sum()`` since you asked to calculate a definite integral (0 to pi). Use ``cumsum()`` for indefinite integrals, i.e., you want to generate a table, from which you can calculate the definite values for different borders.

Comment: `quad` is for integration using adaptive sampling, not for integration from already given samples. Use `trapz(trapz(func_values, rp), pi)`.